# How to refresh observable in RxJava?

Tags: android, functional-programming, reactive-programming, rx-java

I have an observable, which wraps a HTTP request

```
mObservable =  retryObservable(mService.getAddressList(getUserId(), true, 1, Integer.MAX_VALUE, "id", true)
            .map(r -> {
                return r.getItems();
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()));
```

then subscription

```
mSubscription = mObservable.subscribe(items -> {
                mAddressAdapter.swapItems(items);
            }, getActivityBase()::showError);
```

When the subscription initialization comes, cold observable is activated and HTTP request fires. Now, I know that underlying data has changed, and I need to make same, but new request.
I've tried

```
mSubscription.unsubscribe();
```

then calling

```
mObservable.subscribe(items -> {doSomething();})
```

again, as from my understanding, subscribing should trigger the observable, but it doesnt work.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once the `Observable` is completed it doesn't publish any new items. It's Rx contract.

Wrap your code into a method and create a new observable each time.

```
Observable<?> getObservable() {
    return retryObservable(mService.getAddressList(getUserId(), true, 1, Integer.MAX_VALUE, "id", true)
            .map(r -> {
                return r.getItems();
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()));
}
```

As @DaveSexton mentioned in the comment there's even better approach using `defer` function in RxJava

> Do not create the Observable until a Subscriber subscribes; create a
>   fresh Observable on each subscription
>
> Pass defer( ) an Observable factory function (a function that
>   generates Observables), and defer( ) will return an Observable that
>   will call this function to generate its Observable sequence afresh
>   each time a new Subscriber subscribes.

More here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Creating-Observables#defer

Comment: In RxNet we have a factory method for this: [Defer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229160(v=vs.103).aspx). I assume that RxJava has a similar method.

Comment: @DaveSexton Very good point, I'm going to add a link to RxJava defer documentation. Never heard about this before, thanks.